# Multiplication and counting

Tags: combinatorics

A mosquito lives for 5 days. It gives birth at the rate of 2 mosquitoes per day, and this speed of breeding continues till the death of a mosquito. If one mosquito is born in your house today, how many mosquitoes will be there in your house after 10 days?

Comment: Have you tried calculating it by hand? How many mosquitos are there after 1 day, 2 days, 3 days, ..., 10 days?

Comment: Do the mosquito produce only female mosquitoes?

Comment: This author of this question is either remarkably ignorant about mosquito biology, or just doesn't care.

Comment: It sounds like a Fibonacci problems with $2$ possible outcomes but with problems. If only females are produced there are only $1+5\times2-1=10$ mosquitoes after $5$ days  because there are no males to fertilize the females and then none after $10$ days because they all died. If equal numbers of male/female are produced, then the progression is the sum of the original plus offspring plus grand-offspring for $5$ days and then the same but with slight subtraction of the offspring's production after that. I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: Does this mosquito give birth to two at the same time? Or does it give birth to one at noon and one at midnight? When you say breeding, does that require two mosquitoes, or does one just breed by itself? This question is quite a mess, I can understand why you are having trouble solving it.

Comment: I really appreciate different viewpoints put forward by all, as those enrich the scope of analysing the problem from multitude of perspectives. But for the sake of simplicity let us assume, the mosquito is capable of self breeding, the original mosquito is a female and it gives birth to female progenies only, it gives birth to 2 at a time say at noon and we are calculating from noon to noon as the span of a day.

Comment: Presumably, a mosquito does not give birth on the day it's born, but how about on the day it dies?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{matrix}
day & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & sum \\
0 & f_{0,1}=1 & f_{0,2}=0 & f_{0,3}=0 & f_{0,4}=0 & f_{0,5}=0 & f_0=\sum_n f_{0,n}=1 \\
1 & f_{1,1}=2*f_0=2 & f_{1,2}=f_{0,1}=1 & f_{1,3}=f_{0,2}=0 & f_{1,4}=f_{0,3}=0 & f_{1,5}=f_{0,4}=0 & f_1=\sum_n f_{1,n}=3 \\
2 & f_{2,1}=2*f_1=6 & f_{2,2}=f_{1,1}=2 & f_{2,3}=f_{1,2}=1 & f_{2,4}=f_{1,3}=0 & f_{2,5}=f_{1,4}=0 & f_2=\sum_n f_{2n}=9 \\
3 & f_{3,1}=2*f_2=18 & f_{3,2}=f_{2,1}=6 & f_{3,3}=f_{2,2}=2 & f_{3,4}=f_{2,3}=1 & f_{3,5}=f_{2,4}=0 & f_3=\sum_n f_{3,n}=27 \\
4 & f_{4,1}=2*f_3=27 & f_{4,2}=f_{3,1}=18 & f_{4,3}=f_{3,2}=6 & f_{4,4}=f_{3,3}=2 & f_{4,5}=f_{3,4}=1 & f_4=\sum_n f_{4,n}=54 \\
5 & f_{5,1}=2*f_4=54 & f_{5,2}=f_{4,1}=27 & f_{5,3}=f_{4,2}=18 & f_{5,4}=f_{4,3}=6 & f_{5,5}=f_{4,4}=2 & f_5=\sum_n f_{5,n}=107 \\
6 & f_{6,1}=2*f_5=107 & f_{6,2}=f_{5,1}=54 & f_{6,3}=f_{5,2}=27 & f_{6,4}=f_{5,3}=18 & f_{6,5}=f_{5,4}=6 & f_6=\sum_n f_{6,n}=214 \\
7 & f_{7,1}=2*f_6=214 & f_{7,2}=f_{6,1}=107 & f_{7,3}=f_{6,2}=54 & f_{7,4}=f_{6,3}=27 & f_{7,5}=f_{6,4}=18 & f_7=\sum_n f_{7,n}=420 \\
8 & f_{8,1}=2*f_7=420 & f_{8,2}=f_{7,1}=214 & f_{8,3}=f_{7,2}=107 & f_{8,4}=f_{7,3}=54 & f_{8,5}=f_{7,4}=27 & f_8=\sum_n f_{8,n}=822 \\
9 & f_{9,1}=2*f_8=822 & f_{9,2}=f_{8,1}=420 & f_{9,3}=f_{8,2}=214 & f_{9,4}=f_{8,3}=107 & f_{9,5}=f_{8,4}=54 & f_9=\sum_n f_{9,n}=1617 \\
10 & f_{10,1}=2*f_9=1617 & f_{10,2}=f_{9,1}=822 & f_{10,3}=f_{9,2}=420 & f_{10,4}=f_{9,3}=214 & f_{10,5}=f_{9,4}=107 & f_{10}=\sum_n f_{10,n}=3180
\end{matrix}
$$
--- rk